# Fill a Textbox from a File

Tags: vb.net, listview, textbox, text-files

I am making a Help-form for my application. A Help-form normally has a ListView on the left and a RichTextbox on the right. When you click on a Help topic in the ListView, the text in the RichTextbox is supposed to change accordingly. The text file is part of the application's resources.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it.

Since the text file is in Resources, I can do this:

Richtextbox1.Text = My.Resources.Textfile

Answer (score 0):

You need to load the file into memory, and then put it into a string.  When the user clicks the string, TextBox.Value (I think that's the proper property) should be set to the string.

If you're excessively lazy (after all, it is a Saturday), check out this link: http://www.freevbcode.com/ShowCode.Asp?ID=466.  It has what you're looking for, as long as its VB5/6/VBA.  I'm not certain if it will run on VB.net.